# Difference between 'catch(e)' and 'on Exception catch(e)' in dart?

Tags: dart

What is the difference between `catch(e)` and `on Exception catch(e)` in dart?

> AVOID catches without on clauses.
>
> Using catch clauses without on clauses makes your code prone to encountering unexpected errors that won't be thrown (and thus will go unnoticed).

**BAD:**

```
try {
 somethingRisky()
} catch(e) {
  doSomething(e);
}
```

**GOOD:**

```
try {
 somethingRisky()
} on Exception catch(e) {
  doSomething(e);
}
```

Link: [avoid_catches_without_on_clauses](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_catches_without_on_clauses.html)

Comment: [AVOID catches without on clauses](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses)--"A catch clause with no on qualifier catches anything thrown by the code in the try block. is very likely not what you want."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `} on Exception catch (e) {` will catch all thrown objects implementing `Exception`.
The excludes most errors (which implement `Error`),

The `} catch (e) {` will catch all thrown objects, both exceptions and errors - and anything else that might get thrown. Most thrown objects implement either `Exception` or `Error`, but that's just a convention. Any non-`null` object can be thrown.

I'd actually recommend against `on Exception` as well. Exceptions are not errors, they are intended for functions as an alternative to returning a value, but exceptions are still just as much part of the function API, and you should only be catching the exceptions that you are actually planning to handle. Since `Exception` itself has no information, you should be catching the subtype that the function is documented as throwing so you can use the available information to *handle* the exceptional case.
If you are not going to handle it, you might as well treat the exception as an error.

Using only `} catch (e) {` to catch everything is reasonable in some situations, mainly in framework code which wraps other user code, and needs to make sure a user code error or unhandled exception doesn't take down the entire program.